# How to change the border-top-right-radius in css?

Tags: html, css

```css
.file-diagram {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<span class="file-diagram"> TRA</span>
```

How to change the border-top-right-radius in css?

Want to create a file look like diagram like this...

[image]

In font-awesome, I found some useful class  like
 , But I want to do that only with help of css.

Comment: I'll suggest you to make some search on google (tip: triangle and :before / :after pseudoelements), try something and then aske here. For example you can find a lot of question about how to create a triangle (it's a point to start to create your icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clip-path and some gradients:

```css
.box {
  --b:5px;
  --s:20px;
  --c:green;

  width:50px;
  height:60px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  border:var(--b) solid var(--c);
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,calc(100% - var(--s)) 0,100% var(--s),100% 100%,0 100%);
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,var(--c) calc(50% - 0.3*var(--b)),#0000 0),
    conic-gradient(at left var(--b) bottom var(--b),#0000 90deg,var(--c) 0);
  background-position:top right;
  background-size:var(--s) var(--s);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--b:2px;--c:red;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--b:2px;--s:10px;--c:blue;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--b:8px;--s:30px;--c:purple;"></div>
```